# Can sign language be used for public Torah reading?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, language, handicap-disabled-impair

We would like to perform a minyan for the deaf. All the participants can speak verbally, but cannot hear, including the Torah reader. Can he sign the words that he is reading during Kri'at Hatorah, or is there a halacha that the Torah must be specifically oralized and only in Hebrew?

Comment: ASL or Hebrew sign language? (Not sure if this makes a difference.) Also, looks like three separate questions. 1. Oral/speaking, 2. Hebrew only, 3. Does HSL count as Hebrew?

Comment: You should *really* consult a knowledgeable rabbi for this issue.

Comment: I don't think it matters, as deaf people aren't obligated in this mitzvah. That being said, I'm still curious as to the halachic status of sign language.

Comment: Is the obligation\mitzvah to "read" or to "hear?"

Comment: I don't understand the question. the reader is not saying it by heart so what can be wrong with assembling a group of Jewish people to read from the torah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rabbi Dovid Stein of [Beit Kenesset Chatam](http://chatam.org/) in Rehovot has a large group of deaf people come and read Parshas Zachor from the torah every year. Meaning that each individual comes to the torah and reads for himself. Presumably this is because "krias hatorah" needs to be just that - reading from the torah, and sign language is not considered to fit into the *halachik* category of reading.

There are those who say based on the Rambam in [Tefila 12:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2212.htm) that the requirement to read the torah is a requirement of the community, but not of any one specific individual, and therefore if one were to miss some of the reading he does not have to make it up, because he is not individually required to hear it. (This would be in distinction from hearing meggilas Esther on Purim.) If that is the case, the same would hold true for deaf people. They are not individually required to hear the reading, and so it would not be necessary to have the reading signed to them.

Comment: Nice answer. Sorry I'm accepting it just now. Incidentally, according to many opinions, someone wearing cochlear implants may blow the shofar and he can also read megilla for others, despite the fact that he is deaf once he removes them.